# Обработка всех данных PHP

Tags: php, apache

Стала задача обрабатывать все приходящие вперед других скриптов. При этом не должна нарушаться работа других скриптов.
Так же я не знаю конкретного движка, поэтому подключить тем же `includ'ом` не вариант.
Возможно, такое можно осуществить при помощи htaccess? К примеру, возьмем WordPress, как перехватывать все запросы к нужному мне скрипту, а только потом отдавать их CMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в .htaccess опцию:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/путь/к/вашему/скрипту.php"
```

Действует аналогично включению вашего файла с помощью include в самое начало запускаемого скрипта.